# Java Integer Door Combination

Tags: java

I need some help or general advice on why my code isn't functioning as intended.

Background Info: A combination, consisting of 3, 2-digits numbers (between 10-99) is created in a Combination class. The ConnectionManager class (found via the link given below) receives the combination in ascending order (via accessors in Combination assigning them as such Ex. 34 67 87). Loops comprised on nested whiles must go through all possible combinations; stopping when the input combination succeeds, or by hitting the limit (97 98 99). Just to clarify, the 3 integers can't equal one another(Ex. 34 34 97) and defaults 10 11 12 respectively. If the combination is found, the method itself must return a Boolean in order for the next method to continue.

The loop itself must end when either of these 2 conditions are met, otherwise the whole program will fail. I'm struggling to find a way for it to work properly, any kind of help/advice is appreciated.

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    private Combination combo; 
    private Connector connect; 
}

public class ConnectionManager()
{
    combo = new Combination();
    connect = new Connector();


public void unLockDoor(AbstractCombination combo)               
{
    int count = 0; 
    int combo3; 
    int combo2; 
    int combo1; 


for(counter = 0; counter <= 99; counter++)
{
    while(combo3 <= 99)
    {
        while(combo2 < combo3)
        {
            while(combo1 < combo2)
            {
                setCombo();                     //From the combination class to set combination
                if(Connector.unLockDoor(combo) == true)     //From Connector Class
                {
                    unlock = true; 
                }
                else
                {
                    combo1++;

                    if(combo1 == combo2)
                    {
                        combo1 = 10;    
                        combo2++;

                        if(combo2 == combo3)
                        {
                            combo2 = 11; 
                            combo3 = 12; 
                            combo3++;
                        }
                    }

                counter += 1; 
                System.out.println(combo1 + " " + combo2 + " " + combo3 + " " + counter)
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    System.exit(0);

}
}
```

I apologize if there's anything wrong with this post format wise, again point any issues out :)

Comment: You haven't actually stated what the problem is.  What are you expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. You have not initialized your variables. Your constructor is outside of its class, and you are not using the actual fields that you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code doesn't compile due to syntax errors, because you have 'class' in your constructor declaration. Change:

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    private Combination combo; 
    private Connector connect; 
}

public class ConnectionManager()
{
    combo = new Combination();
    connect = new Connector();
```

to

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    private Combination combo; 
    private Connector connect; 


    public ConnectionManager()
    {
        combo = new Combination();
        connect = new Connector();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
          if(combo2 == combo3)
                    {
                        combo2 = 11; 
                        combo3 = 12; 
                        combo3++;
                    }
```

Which resets combo3 to 13 whenever combo2 reaches the value of combo3.